# Is there any better way to judge whether mounted?

Tags: flutter, dart

Sometimes we need judge whether `mounted` before `setState`:

```dart
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    _detailModel = model;
  });
}
```

For example in http request we always do as above in order to avoid throw error `setState() called after dispose()` when back to previous page.

It's OK to write `if (mounted)`, but I did forget to write it sometimes.

So I wonder is there any better way to avoid throw error when forget judge `mounted`.

What's your ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I write an extension for `State`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

extension StateExtension on State {
  void setStateIfMounted(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(fn);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
setStateIfMounted(() {
  _color = Colors.green;
});
```

What's more, you will get hint every time tap `sets` so you would not forget what you should do.

[image]

Comment: it says "The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'."

Comment: @Texv Yes, anyway can avoid this warning?

Comment: @Texv Are there any downsides to using this StateExtension? By that, can I change every setState() in my project to setStateIfMounted()? If so why does not Flutter enable this check mounted behaviour as default?